# Importing CSV with commas in string values

Tags: postgresql, csv, postgresql-8.4, postgresql-copy

I am trying to import a trivial CSV to Postgres 8.4 database:

Here is a table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.sample (
  a VARCHAR, 
  b VARCHAR
) WITHOUT OIDS;
```

Here is a CSV file sample:

```
"foo","bar, baz"
```

The query:

```
COPY sample FROM '/tmp/sample.csv' USING DELIMITERS ',';
```

Throws an exception:

```
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY sample, line 1: ""foo","bar, baz""
```

But, well, CSV parsing is not rocket science and I wonder if it is not possible to solve without reformatting the source CSV file.

Input comes from a 3rd party, I cannot change the format.
(I understand I could pre-process to change the delimiter before I import it.)

**Final solution**:

```
COPY sample FROM '/tmp/sample.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

Originally taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9682174/251311, and documentation page is http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-copy.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clearly, you have a CSV file while you try to import it as text format.  For Postgres 9.1 or newer, use:

```
COPY sample FROM '/tmp/sample.csv' (FORMAT csv);
```

The default delimiter for CSV format is the comma (`,`) anyway. [More in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html).
For PostgreSQL 8.4 or older:

```
COPY sample FROM '/tmp/sample.csv' CSV;
```

Comment: For 8.4 the syntax is slightly different though http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: @zerkms: Right, the syntax is for the current version 9.1. I added the 8.4 variant for documentation.

Comment: Just a quick comment for those who are now on version 10.x - syntax now is more like

`COPY sample FROM '/tmp/sample.csv' WITH FORMAT (CSV, DELIMITER ',', NULL ' ');`