# Trying to import a CSV file into postgres with comma as delimeter

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to import a CSV file into Posgres that has a comma as delimiter.  I do:

```
\COPY products(title, department) from 'toyd.csv' with (DELIMITER ',');
```

All super cool.

However, `title` and `department` are both strings. I have some commas that are in these columns that I don't want to be interpreted as delimiters.  So I pass the strings in quotes.  But this doesn't work. Postgres still thinks they are delimiters.  What are my missing?

Here is a snippet from the CSV that causes the problem:

```
"Light","Reading, Writing & Spelling"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How are the commas escaped? There are different patterns but the two I am familiar with is ',,' == ',' or '\,' = ','. If I remember correctly the previous is a more standard csv.

Comment: If these quotes are double quotes, this should work. Otherwise, maybe show a part of your CSV file.

Comment: If it is possible, then you can try changing the delimiter manually and then importing it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001651/importing-csv-and-commas-in-string-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't using CSV format there, just a comma-delimited one.

Tell it you want [FORMAT CSV](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) and it should default to quoted text - you could also change the quoting character if necessary.